# Angular - Display data based on userID gives error

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I use Angular 7 and Laravel 5.8 to develop an Application.

Laravel: Backend

```
    public function indexSmsmo()
{
    if(Auth::user()->id == 1)
         $smsmos = Smsmo::all();
    else 
     $smsmos = Smsmo::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
    return $smsmos;               
}
```

I have user table and other tables.  The other tables has user_id in them.

auth.service.ts

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.prod';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {


public currentUser: User;
   private readonly apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
   private environmentService: EnvironmentService;

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router) 
    {     
    }

onLogin(user: User): Observable<User> {

const request = JSON.stringify(
  { email: user.email, password: user.password }
);

return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, request, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map((response: User) => {
      // Receive jwt token in the response
      const token: string = response['access_token'];
      // If we have a token, proceed
      if (token) {
        this.setToken(token);
        this.getUser().subscribe();
      }
      return response;
    }),
    catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
  );
}
```

After this we have login component

login.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
 document.body.className = 'hold-transition login-page';
 $(() => {
  $('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
    increaseArea: '20%' /* optional */
  });
});

//  Set the return url
this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/home';
this.authService.onLogout();
}

onSubmit(loginForm): void {
this.spinnerService.show();
this.authService.onLogin(this.user).subscribe(
  (response) => {      

    this.notify.success('Done, you have successfully logged in.', {timeout:2000, position: "rightTop"})        
    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);       
  },
  (error) => {
    this.spinnerService.hide();
    this.error = error.error;
  }
);
// Clear form fields
loginForm.reset();
 }
```

When I tried to click on the menu to display data from any of the other tables from the end point I got this error:

[image: local_error]

Then as I checked the console, I got this:

[image: console_error]

However, if I remove the condition from the end point and made the controller as:

```
    public function indexSmsmo()
{       

     $smsmos = Smsmo::all();
     return $smsmos;        
}
```

instead of the initial:

```
    public function indexSmsmo()
{
    if(Auth::user()->id == 1)
         $smsmos = Smsmo::all();
    else 
     $smsmos = Smsmo::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
    return $smsmos;               
}
```

No error, but it displays everything.  How do I achieve my goal.

If a user logs in and the user_id is 1, he should see everything, but if it is not 1, he should see on data with user_id equals to the login ID

Comment: Do you have CORS enabled in your server?

Comment: I have dealt with CORS issue.

Comment: Status 0 is a CORS issue, is your POST request returning data,are you sending any credential to the backend? If so, have you tried with the withCredentials:true flag?